# Function calls in Assembly Language

Tags: assembly

I am trying to make a simple program in Simple RISC. I need to make a function call inside a while loop(return type int). Can this be implemented without using stack pointer? (Attaching my C++ code for reference)

```
while(k>0){
    int p=k%10;
    int r=power(p);     //power returns p^p
 result+=r;
 k=k/10;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you want to use the stack pointer?

Comment: So inline the body of `power()` into your loop...

Answer (score 0):

As I understood from the tag, you want to implement the function on riscv.

yes you can do it without stack pointer, it's a very simple function, however if it is more complicated, you can also avoid using stack pointer, but you need to save your temporary variables and registers somewhere on the stack.

Here is the code:

```
;a0 function arg, a3 return value
;x0 is hardwired to 0,
.text
.globl  power
.type   power , @function


power:
add a3,x0,1
add a4,a0,0
power_0:
mul a3,a3,a0
add a4,a4,-1
bnez  a4,power_0
jr ra
```

I don't see the point of avoiding the stack pointer, but if you state the full problem, there can be a better solution

Comment: Doesn't your "power" function only work for `p=1..2`?  It returns `p*p`, i.e. `p**2`, not `p**p`